# How to find the last 2 letters in an alpha numeric string?

Tags: excel

I have a column of alpha numeric addresses with no punctuation. In all cells, the state is the last 2 letters (abbreviation) followed by the ZIP. However, sometimes the ZIP is 5 letters and sometimes its xxxxx-xxxx so mid()right() wont work. Can anyone think of a formula that will work?

Comment: What version of Excel are you using? Can you post a few data examples with the expected output and whatever formula's you've tried?

Comment: what programming language are you trying to use?

Answer (score 0):

If those are the only two options: `#####` and `#####-####` then:

```
=MID(A1,LEN(A1)-IF(ISNUMBER(--MID(A1,LEN(A1)-5,1)),11,6),2)
```

[image]